# When is the find() method actually necessary?

Tags: entries, queries

I've noticed code samples like the following that use the `find()` method.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog').limit(5).find() %}
    <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I've noticed that this code sample works just as well without the `find()` method attached. Is there a particular reason we use `find()`? Are there instances where it's required? Should I be using it even if the code works without it?

Comment: Hi Tim - I asked the same thing a while ago - I think it was within Slack though. Someone else will give a much better answer I'm sure but...When working with entries the `.find()` is implied. Craft will do it automatically and it won't hurt anything if you call it. There are other times where `find()` is implied but I forget what that is.

There are other cases though where you do need to call `find()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ElementCriteraModel description in the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) explains what the [`find()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#find) method does.

Essentially, when you use `craft.entries` you are building an `ElementCriteriaModel` object that represents the query that you want to make. That query doesn't actually happen until you call the `find()` method.

As the docs state, as soon as you treat `craft.entries` (or a variable that you have assigned it to) as an array, by using it in a `{% for %}` loop, or by calling the `| length` filter on it, `find()` is automatically called.

So in the example in your question, you can safely leave out the `find()` and it will be called automatically anyway when the `{% for %}` loop is executed.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a really good answer explained in this ticket. Similar explanation but this made it click for me.

https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/23951/4433