# Returning ElementCriteriaModel of entries via plugin

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel

I'm outputting an element criteria model in a Craft 2 plugin of some entries in a channel.  I noticed that when I fetch the entries the standard template way

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('channelHandle') %}
```

I am then able to do something like the following to refine the number of entries with the lightswitch turned on:

```
{% set refinedEntries = entries.customLightswitchField(1)|length %}
```

However, when I fetch my entries in my plugin, output them into the template, then try refining it as above:

```
// plugin
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'channelHandle';
$entries = $criteria->find();
return $entries;

// template
{% set entries = craft.myPlugin.fetch() %}
{% set refinedEntries = entries.customLightswitchField(1)|length %}
```

...I then get an `Array to string conversion` PHP notice.  I'm also not able to use things like `.first()` like I normally would.

Is this expected behavior?  Am I missing something when returning an element criteria model through a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is the expected behavior because you don't return an `ElementCriteriaModel` from your plugin.

You do `return $criteria->find();` so you'll return an array of entries but not an `ElementCriteriaModel` if you want to return the object instead of the entries you have to do `return $criteria`.

As soon as you use the `find()` method Craft builds a query based on your `ElementCriteriaModel`, executes it and returns you an array of elements or null.